# Multiple DB update queries in a single function

Tags: javascript, database

Just curious about how to safely handle multiple update queries in a single function.

Suppose I have below JavaScript code,

```
collection1.firstUpdate(post, (err,data) =>{
  if(err) console.log("fail 1");
  else{
    collection2.secondUpdate(user, (err,data)=>{
      if(err) console.log("fail 2");
      else{
        console.log("sucess!");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

If `secondUpdate()` catches an error, it seems like `collection1` has already been updated from `firstUpdate()`. In this case, do I have to manually delete updated document from `firstUpdate`?

Please advise with typical way to handle multiple update queries.

Comment: What kind of document store? I assume noSQL? Because you've discovered why transactions and classic RDBMS systems were invented. And why noSQL didn't kill SQL. :)

Comment: Whatever database you're using should have an implementation of transactions, and whatever data access library you're using should have a way to use them.  A transaction allows you to roll up multiple database interactions into a more atomic operation.

Comment: I am using MongoDB and mongoose. However, I can't find any document related to this.. @David